# Can't generate anything using rails-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, rails-api

I'm trying to set up a rails json api using the rails-api gem but I'm having a little trouble getting it to work like it should.

I'm following this tutorial since I'll be creating this for an ember.js frontend.

http://blog.jasonkriss.com/building-an-app-with-ember-app-kit-part-1/

And bundling (after fixing the [ issue on line 3) works.

When I attempt to generate the model that he generates after bundling I just get something that looks like this in the terminal...

```
/Users/jordanriser/workspace/Test/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<Test::Application:0x007f9bcb9b0640> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/jordanriser/workspace/Test/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/jordanriser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've googled that "undefined method 'configure'" But I can't seem to find any definitive answers on what that is.

Comment: You removed active records from your app. Which database you are using in your app? Also check your configurations in config...

Comment: The tutorial I linked to is using postgres, and I don't recall removing anything but maybe the database is doing that?
Also when creating the app with `rails-api new` the tutorial says to `--skip-sprockets` is that causing an issue?

Comment: I think --skip-sprockets is is not causing an issue..Can you check config/environments/development.rb look like? It seems you have written configure into it but all settings should be config.something..

Comment: Also in this blog reference rails code is given on this link https://github.com/jasonkriss/contacts-server try to install this code on your local system...

Comment: Summit, downloading the code from that github is allowing me to generate things just fine. My development.rb file in that dir looks the same as the one on that github as well.

Comment: Need some more analysis then...for me blog seems fine...please check your gem versions...and compare those with the git code...